# How do I edit info feature attributes in GeoServer with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

Can you help me?  I have a very difficult problem when doing project...

I have used OpenLayers and GeoServer. When I click in the map to get feature info, I receive the info for the feature and region clicked.

Example: RegionName:Hanoi,Population:500...

I want to know how I can change the attribute value "RegionName" from Hanoi to HaThanh and save it in Geoserver. After I load the map I wish to receive the changed information.

Example: RegionName:HaThanh,Population:500...

Help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

beside @dariapra's answer, there is really good documentation [here](http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html) about OpenLayers WFS-T Using a GeoServer Hosted PostGIS Layer which you should check out.

[image]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: website doesnt work, I kinda have the same problem now

Answer (score 4):

A technology that can help you with this issue is transactional WFS (WFS-T). In the case of GeoServer, WFS-T requires the use of a PostGIS database as data source. On the client side, the following OpenLayers example can be helpful: [WFS Transaction Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html).

Comment: Link broken here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might want to save the data to some data source, either a spatial database or some files that can store spatial data(shp, gml, etc.). Geoserver is just a software server used for publishing geospatial data from some spatial data source, but not a place to store the data. If so, then you might want to check out openlayers [Requesting Remote Data](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/request.html). You'll also need to do some server-side programming to save the submitted data from the client(browser) to database. Then next time you retrieve maps from Geoserver, it will get updated data from database.